# Inverse of a matrix and a scalar

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm asked o find $$\det((ad-bc)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c& d \end{bmatrix})$$

what I did was :

This would equal to

$$\det (\begin{bmatrix}\cfrac{1}{(ad-bc)} & 0 \\ 0 & \cfrac{1}{(ad-bc)} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c& d\end{bmatrix})$$

and this would also equal to

$$\det(\begin{bmatrix}\cfrac{1}{(ad-bc)} & 0 \\ 0 & \cfrac{1}{(ad-bc)} \end{bmatrix})\det(\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\c &d  \end{bmatrix})$$

When calculating this :

$$(ad-bc)^{2}(ad-bc)^{-1}$$ is what you end up with so the answer would be

$$(ad-bc)^{}$$

but the textbook says that the correct answer is 
$$\cfrac{1}{(ad-bc)}$$

How come? What did I do wrong here? I couldn't understand I simply used

$$\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$$

Comment: Your first matrix has det equal to (ad-bc)^{-2} and the second ad-bc. Then, the answer is (ad-bc)^(-1)

Comment: By the way you should not write $1/ad-bc$ when you mean $1/(ad-bc)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your work up to the line

$$\det(\begin{bmatrix}1/ad-bc & 0 \\ 0 & 1/ad-bc \end{bmatrix})det(\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\c &d  \end{bmatrix})$$
is correct.
However, the value of this is
$$\frac{1}{(ad-bc)^2}(ad-bc)=\frac{1}{ad-bc}$$

Comment: ;Ah I see, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One may use that here
$$
\det (c\cdot A)=c^2\cdot \det (A)
$$ giving
$$
\begin{align}
\det\left((ad-bc)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c& d \end{bmatrix}\right)&=(ad-bc)^{-2}\det\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c& d \end{bmatrix}
\\\\&=(ad-bc)^{-2} (ad-bc)
\\\\&=(ad-bc)^{-1}
\end{align}
$$ as announced.